# GoogleScraper keeps searches in database

Tags: python, bash, web-scraping

I am using **GoogleScraper** for some automated searches in python.
**GoogleScraper** keeps search results for search queries in its database named **google_scraper.db.**
e.g. if i have searched site:*.us engineering books and due to internet issue while making json file by GoogleScraper.
If the result is missed and json file is not like that what it must be then when i again search that command using GoogleScraper it gives same result while internet is working fine,
i mean to say GoogleScraper maintains its database for a query which it has searched and does not search again it, when i search that command whose result is stored in database,it does not give new result but give results from database stored previously

Comment: To understand what your issue is, I tried to reformat your paragraph-long sentence into shorter sentences. However, you may want to do the same for the part that starts at _If a query result is missed_, as I have no clue what you meant there.

Comment: e.g. if i have searched  **site:*.us engineering books** and due to internet issue while making json file by **GoogleScraper**,if the result is missed and json file is not like that what it must be then when i again search that command using **GoogleScraper** it gives same result while internet is working fine, i mean to say **GoogleScraper** maintains its **database** for a query which it has searched and does not search again it, when i search that command whose result is stored in **database**,it does not give new result but give results from database stored previously.

Comment: Qasam, May I suggest you break your paragraph-long-sentances to a group of short sentances? Also, Instead of explaining in a comment - you can go back to the OP (Original Post), and _edit_ it.

Comment: no one is picking my point, every one is suggesting to change view, i know you are saying right but you should also answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue which keeps searches in **GoogleScraper database**,we first have to run following command
    **GoogleScraper --clean**
This command cleans all cache and we can search again with new results.

**Regards!**